# Unknown service DeviceConnectionServiceBroker

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, services

I've found a `DeviceConnectionServiceBroker` among the google services. I can't find what does this do and a google search didn't help, which seems strange to me. What is this service for? I have lollipop on my phone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=DeviceConnectionServiceBroker) did help, but reaaaaally a little. Other than this question, the search returned [a PasteBin entry](http://pastebin.com/AnHV5HFP), with snippet `com.google.android.gms.deviceconnection.service.DeviceConnectionServiceBroker`. The only hint from the package name is `gms`, which is related to [Google Play service](https://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html). However, since it's NOT open-sourced, my investigation got stuck there....

Comment: You are right, indeed... Still curious about what it is though